# How to use an event as If statement condition

Tags: vba, ms-access, events

I want to write a code for my form that when user clicks on each of text boxes to enter the data, textbox background change to green.

Something like this - in form current event:

```
Dim c as control
For each c In me.controls
  If c.OnClick then
     C.backcolor= vbGreen
     C.tag="clicked"
  End If
  If c.AfterUpdate and c.tag="clicked" then
     C.backcolor= vbWhite
     C.tag=""
Next c
```

How can I find out when an event is triggered?

Comment: I don't want to call the event for each textbox separately and one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use *WithEvents* for that. This is poorly documented, but an example can be found in my project (too much code to post here):

[VBA.ModernTheme](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernTheme)

Full documentation and further links are in my article on the project:

[Create Windows Phone Colour Palette and Selector using WithEvents](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29554/Create-Windows-Phone-Colour-Palette-and-Selector-using-WithEvents.html?preview=yawJg2wkMzc%3D)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your program is very applicable and its WithEvents part help me so much. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two functions in your form code as follows:

```
Private Function SetBackColor()
    Me.ActiveControl.BackColor = vbGreen
End Function

Private Function ResetBackColor()
    Me.ActiveControl.BackColor = vbWhite
End Function
```

Then set the `On Got Focus` property of all the text boxes to `=SetBackColor()`
and the `On Lost Focus` property of all text boxes to `=ResetBackColor()`

This can be done easily by selecting all text boxes and write the property once and it will apply to all of them (no need to repeat the writes).

This will work whenever the user tries to edit any text box even if it was reached by TAB or ENTER buttons not only mouse click.

Comment: Thank you for your solution but it is a bit hand-operated